# How to cut String after a / regarding different length & turn into rows - (SQL Athena)

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

im currently working on cutting the path from our webserver requests log.
these are in the data type string, have different lengths and look something like this:

```
/v1/facility/username
/v1/facility/username/action?utm_parameter
/signinnext=/oauth2/authorize/utm_parameter
```

what i want to do is to cut these stings per / and put them into rows

it should be looked like this

```
name1      |  name2   | name3        | name4
------     | ------   | ------       | ----
v1         | facility | username     | NULL
v1         | facility | username     | action?utm_parameter
signinnext=| oauth2   | authorize    | utm_parameter
```

how do i code this with SQL in Athena?

Comment: You have 4 columns named 'name', how is this going to work?

Comment: @CookieMonster, can be done, but pretty useless in most cases.

Comment: and they are just random names for a example

Answer (score 0):

#### Option 1: split_part

```
select  split_part (path,'/',2) as name1
       ,split_part (path,'/',3) as name2
       ,split_part (path,'/',4) as name3
       ,split_part (path,'/',5) as name4

from    mytable
;
```

---

```
    name1    |  name2   |   name3   |        name4
-------------+----------+-----------+----------------------
 v1          | facility | username  | NULL
 v1          | facility | username  | action?utm_parameter
 signinnext= | oauth2   | authorize | utm_parameter
```

#### Option 2: regexp_extract

```
select  regexp_extract (path,'(/([^/]*)){1}',2) as name1
       ,regexp_extract (path,'(/([^/]*)){2}',2) as name2
       ,regexp_extract (path,'(/([^/]*)){3}',2) as name3
       ,regexp_extract (path,'(/([^/]*)){4}',2) as name4

from    mytable
;
```

---

```
    name1    |  name2   |   name3   |        name4
-------------+----------+-----------+----------------------
 v1          | facility | username  | NULL
 v1          | facility | username  | action?utm_parameter
 signinnext= | oauth2   | authorize | utm_parameter
```